# Understanding a theorem of limit functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

- Theorem. If $A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $c$ is a limit point of $A$ then $f$ can have only one limit.

My question is if there is not an limit point of $f$, then what about the theorem? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you mean "if $c$ is not a limit point of $A$".

In that case $f$ has more than one limit, in fact every number is a  limit.

Suppose $|x-c|>1$ for every $x\in A$ except $x=c$. Suppose $L\in\mathbb R$. Suppose $\epsilon>0$. Let $\delta=1$. Then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for every $x\in A$ with $0<|x-c|<\delta$, just because there are no such $x$.

So for every $L$, $f(x)\to L$ as $x\to a$.

**Edit:** Or in any case we've verified all of the definition of "$f(x)\to L$ as $x\to a$" except for the requirement that $a$ be a limit point of $A$, *if* that's included.

I couldn't  bear to write the conclusion in "$\lim$" notation, because then we'd have $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=1$, leading to $0=1$. This is because the notation $\lim$ presupposes that we're talking about *the* limit.

Seems to me that whether people do or not they really should require that $a$ be a limit point of $A$ in the definition. Especially when using the "\lim$" notation.

Comment: But if there is a limit, then it is unique, how can we say $f$ has more than one limit?

Comment: Evidently limits are simply _not_ unique unless $c$ is a limit point of $A$.

Comment: Okey, thanks for answer.

Comment: So, Do you remember proof of the theorem? I have a question: Since I don't understand last statement I will not write complete proof. Now, let $L_1, L_2$ be limits of $f$ at $c$. We need to show that $L_1=L_2$., (...) After after..., we obtain $\left| L_{1}-l_{2}\right|=\left| L_1-f\left( x\right) \right|+\left| L_1-f\left( x\right) \right|=\varepsilon /2+\varepsilon /2=\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon>0$ an arbitrary, we conclude $L_1-L_2=0$. Hence, $L_1=L_2$. I didn't understand that why Since $\varepsilon>0$ an arbitrary, we conclude $L_1-L_2=0$? Can you explain?

Comment: If $L_1\ne L_2$ let $\epsilon=|L_1-L_2|/2$. Then $\epsilon>0$ but $|L_1-L_2|>\epsilon$. So if on the other we have $|L_1-L_2|<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$ it follows that $L_1=L_2$.

Comment: Thanks for answer.